# Importing Google Contacts in Windows Contacts

Tags: windows-7, unicode, contacts, google-contacts, vcard

In Windows 7 there is a very simple contact application, Windows Contacts, and I was trying to populate it with contacts from Gmail.

I exported all of them as a single vCard (.vcf) file from Google and used the import function in Windows Contacts. There are two problems though.

- Windows Contacts asks for a confirmation for every single file to import. When there are hundreds of them, this is extremely annoying.
- Gmail vCard file is in UTF-8 format, which is suitable for non-English charsets, anyway, Windows Contacts is unable to read  these characters properly (e.g. Cyrillic).

Do you know how is it possible to avoid confirmation and import Unicode characters properly?

P.S. I have tried also to save and import contacts in CSV, but this is a real no-go, since Windows Contacts asks to remap every Google contact field into its equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Contact Confirmation

#### Windows Address book, Single vCard (vcf) prompting for confirmation of every contact.

**Workaround:** Give it a second vCard with one or more *unique* contacts, it won't ask for confirmation of *every* contact in the files.

I verified by entering 8 contacts into iCloud and exported a 6 to one single vCard and 2 to another vCard.

**Caveat:** Provided there are no duplicates, it shouldn't prompt to confirm.

HowTo

1. Cleanup Duplicates
2. Export single vCard File with multiple contacts
3. Export another single vCard file with 1 or more unique contacts
4. Place VCF's in a directory on your desktop.
5. Open windows 7 Windows address book. [Windows Start] + RUN.  type <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>
6. Click the **Import** button from the ribbon.
7. Select vCard (VCF File)
8. Click the **Import** button
9. browse to the vcf directory on your desktop from step 4
10. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click once on each VCF.
11. Click the **Open** button.
12. After progress bar finishes, click the **Close** button on the Import Dialog.

Done.

### What now.

With your bulk contacts in the **Windows Address Book**, you can now export them into a more accessible format.  - CSV

no comment on UTF-8 or Cyrillic characters